# Given 2 sorted lists A and B, find all elements of B that are NOT in A

Tags: python

I wish to find all elements of B that are NOT in A, given that both lists are sorted and numeric. I understand that there are ways of doing this in python that make this trivially easy (e.g. using setdiff()), but I'm looking for a more specific approach using moving index flags.

This is the easiest way to accomplish this, if we do a sweeping comparison of all elements.

```
def exclude_list(list_a, list_b):
    ret_list = []
    for element_b in list_b:
        if element_b not in list_a:
            ret_list.append(element_b)
    return ret_list
```

I wish to use a moving index approach, using "pointers" idx_a and idx_b. Since both lists are sorted, if list_b[idx_b] < list_a[idx_a], the element from B is immediately added to the result. The following is what I've come up with, but I duplicate code in multiple places and I'm not sure if there's a more elegant solution:

```
def exclude_list_fast(list_a, list_b):
    ret_list = []

    # 3 scenarios,
    #   1. list_b[idx_b] < list_a[idx_a], immediately add into ret_list.
    #        - idx_b += 1
    #        - no change to idx_a
    #   2. list_b[idx_b] = list_a[idx_a], item is found.
    #       - idx_b += 1
    #       - no change to idx_a
    #   3. list_b[idx_b] > list_a[idx_a], item may still be ahead.
    #       - idx_a += 1
    #       - no change to idx_b
    #       - compare again until result falls within the first 2 cases

    idx_a = 0

    for idx_b in range(len(list_b)):

        # If idx_a has already reached max length, add to the ret_list.
        if idx_a == len(list_a)-1:
            ret_list.append(list_b[idx_b])
        elif list_b[idx_b] < list_a[idx_a]:
            ret_list.append(list_b[idx_b])
        elif list_b[idx_b] == list_a[idx_a]:
            continue
        elif list_b[idx_b] > list_a[idx_a]:
            while list_b[idx_b] > list_a[idx_a] and idx_a < (len(list_a)-1):
                idx_a += 1
                if list_b[idx_b] < list_a[idx_a]:
                    ret_list.append(list_b[idx_b])
                elif list_b[idx_b] == list_a[idx_a]:
                    break

    return ret_list
```

Would love to know if there's a more elegant, computationally efficient solution that uses moving indexes. I'd appreciate any sort of constructive guidance.

Comment: does it have to be "moving index flags"? why not use sets?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very easily with [set](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) methods. The [difference](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.difference) method could help you in this particular case:

```
>>> l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> l2 = ['a', 'c', 'x', 'y']
>>> set(l2).difference(l1)
set(['y', 'x'])
```

If you absolutely need a list, you can cast the result:

```
>>> list(set(l2).difference(l1))
['y', 'x']
```

Comment: I understand set difference would have made this trivial. I'm just looking for the moving index approach as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now your problem is with the `in` with a list which has a linear time or `O(n)`, and because the two lists are sorted, you can do it using the following algorithm:

```
#1)loop over B
#2)look for B[i] using Binary Search because it is sorted, and save the index in indexA
#3)next item in B, look for it again in Binary search in list_a but after last index where you last left
def exclude_list(list_a, list_b):
    ret_list = []
    start_in_list_a = 0 
    for element_b in list_b:
        index_of_item_in_list_b = binary_search(element_b,list_a,start_in_list_a )
        if index_of_item_in_list_b == -1:
            ret_list.append(element_b)
        else:
            start_in_list_a = index_of_item_in_list_b 
    return ret_list
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with a generator function yielding the results instead of returning a `list`, this can be done very simply and elegantly:

```py
def iterdiff(a, b):
    """Yields values from b that are not present in a.

    Both a and b must be sorted iterables of comparable types.
    """
    exhausted = object()
    existing = iter(a)
    next_existing = next(existing, exhausted)
    for candidate in b:
        while next_existing is not exhausted and next_existing < candidate:
            next_existing = next(existing, exhausted)
        if next_existing is exhausted or next_existing > candidate:
            yield candidate
```

This implementation runs in O(n + m) time, and is guaranteed to iterate `b` exactly once and `a` at most once. It also works with any iterable, not just lists.

If you really wanted to return a `list` object, you could easily adapt it to build up the result instead, but I think the generator form is much more elegant.

To explain how this works:

We keep two "pointers" to the two input iterables, in the form of iterator objects: the implicit iterator from the `for` loop is iterating over `b` and the explicit iterator object `existing` is iterating over `a`.

Our primary loop is over the `b` iterable. At each iteration we need to decide to either yield the object from `b` (if it is unique) or not yield it (if it duplicates an object from `existing`).

If `existing` is "behind" (less than) our `candidate` object, we keep moving forward in `a` until we find an object that is equal to or greater than our `candidate` (or until we reach the end of `a`).

If `existing` is "ahead of" (greater than) our `candidate` object, we yield the `candidate`, since it cannot exist in `a`. (If it were in `a`, we would have reached it already, and since both lists are sorted we know we can't have reached it without considering this candidate.) We will continue to yield candidates from `b` until we catch up to the value of the `existing` iterator (or until we reach the end of `b`).

If the `existing` value is equal to our `candidate` object, we don't yield the `candidate`, thus omitting it from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems correct, but possible to simplify further. You can iterate over one list directly while maintaining an index over the other one:

```
i = 0
for x in a:
    # skip entries in b that are smaller than x
    while i < len(b) and b[i] < x:
        i += 1
    # if we moved past x, it's not in b, and can be emitted.
    if b[i] > x:
        yield x
```

Strictly speaking, the other one can also be iterated and doesn't require accessing the list via an index directly. That requires explicit `iter()` and `next()` calls, and catching the StopIteration exception. (The advantage of this code would be that both arguments can be arbitrary iterable values and don't need to be lists.)

```
ib = iter(b)
try:
    y = next(ib)
except StopIteration:
    y = None
for x in a:
    try:
        # skip entries in b that are smaller than x
        while y < x:
            y = next(ib)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    # if we moved past x, it's not in b, and can be emitted.
    if y != x:
        yield x
```

In both cases, the code returns a generator, but it can easily be turned into a list by calling `list()` on it.